# Отсутствие перевода при получении доступа к очереди на закрытие

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Вот так всегда... Заработал новую привилегию, а там на каком-то нерусском...
Перевод предлагать не буду: думаю, он просто слетел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `а там на каком-то нерусском` — XD. Хорош кодер ;)

Comment: Еще стоит обратить внимание на _"Присуждается за **3k** баллов репутации"_ - ожидается _"3тыс. баллов"_... или хотя бы _"3 килобаллов"_(если в СИ).

Comment: @yar85 Честно говоря, не вижу в этом острой необходимости. ***k*** стало уже настолько частым обозначением тысячи, что все (а **тем более** программисты, для коих сайт и предназначен) должны понять.

Comment: @Максим, это замечание было именно к полноте перевода, а не его понятности. Для большой части программистов, привыкших читать доки на инглише, и весь UI на английском был бы понятен - но интерфейс все же переводится на русский (ибо сама специфика сайта к этому обязывает). А сокращение это в данном случае не самостоятельная сущность, а часть текста... поэтому, сокращение надо тоже перевести (лишь потому, что иначе перевод текста будет неполным, частичным, "двуязыковым").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложил: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16640

> Если достаточное количество участников проголосует **Оставить открытым**, вопрос удаляется из очереди голосования за закрытие.

Строки, которые видны только при получении привилегий, имеют крайне высокий шанс висеть без перевода, потому что модераторы и мы с αλεχολυτ давно получили эти привилегии и поэтому не видим эти сообщения... Кроме того, ранее таких длинных всплывающих сообщений при получении новой привилегии вообще не было, я только сейчас узнал о их существовании. Эта строка была добавлена 08.06.2021, заметили 01.08 - не так уж плохо.

Comment: Можно вопрос: как вы нашли эту строку? Я пытался предложить свой перевод, искал строку по русскому переводу, но она не отобразилась...

Comment: @МаксимФисман если строка не переведена, конечно, нужно искать не по переводу, а по исходной строке. Вводите в source regex любой фрагмент английской строки, тогда все найдется.

Comment: Да, видимо я тупанул и пытался вбить английскую строку в `Translation Regex` :)